# "Rounding" whole numbers in Java

Tags: java, math, rounding

I have a need to take a `long` and round its value down to the nearest 10s place. Hence:

```
If the # is:            Then it should become:
==============================================
243                     240
288485                  288480
6                       0
107                     100
1009                    1000
1019                    1010
```

I know that `RoundingMode` can *probably* help me here, but all the examples I've been able to find use decimals, not whole numbers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Use modulo

Example :

```
 int i= 243;
 System.out.println(i-(i%10));
```

Other way:(taken from duplicate question)

```
 int i = 243;
 MathUtils.round((double) i, -1); // nearest ten, 240.0
 MathUtils.round((double) i, -2); // nearest hundred, 200.0
 MathUtils.round((double) i, -3); // nearest thousand, 2000.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a multiplication and division operation. Integer divsion will round down as you want:

```
long roundDownToTen(long input){
    long intermediate = input/10;
    return input*10;
}
```

For example, if input is 1024, the division causes intermediate to be 102 (since the actual value is 102.4 which is truncated to be stored in a long), and multiplication gives 1020.

You may also use an approach in which you subtract the value of the units digit (modulo), which is suggested in Aeshang's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Divide by 10 (243/10 = 24.3) Put this in an int, multiply by 10. (24*10 = 240)
Do this for all values and you should have the correct value